# JPEG-LS: How to pick T1, T2 and T3 preset coding parameters?

Tags: image-compression, jpeg, jpeg-ls

I am reading `ISO/IEC 14495-1 : 1999 (E)`. Under section `C.2.4.1.1 JPEG-LS preset coding parameters`, one can find the valid values for T1, T2, T3 and RESET. I am interested in selecting **"optimized"** T1,T2,T3 value for lossless compression (NEAR=0).

The table `Table C.1 – LSE marker segment parameter sizes and values for JPEG-LS preset coding parameters` simply gives lower and upper bounds:

| Parameter | Values |
| --- | --- |
| T1 | 0, or NEAR + 1 ≤ T1 ≤ MAXVAL |
| T2 | 0, or T1 ≤ T2 ≤ MAXVAL |
| T3 | 0, or T2 ≤ T3 ≤ MAXVAL |
| RESET | 0, or 3 ≤ RESET ≤ max(255, MAXVAL) |

I fail to understand how those presets actually works/drive the compression process. How can pick T1, T2 or T3 to achieve a better compression ratios? If that simplify the problem: MAXVAL=65535 for me,  and since I am only interested in lossless compression: NEAR=0.

References:

- [Overview of JPEG LS](https://jpeg.org/jpegls/index.html)
- [T.87 : Information technology – Lossless and near-lossless compression of continuous-tone still images – Baseline](https://www.itu.int/rec/T-REC-T.87/en)
- [Evaluation of JPEG-LS, the new lossless and near-lossless still image compression standard, for compression of high-resolution elevation data](https://www.ima.umn.edu/sites/default/files/1720.pdf)